# Grooy/Grails or Java : viewing YouTube videos marked private

Tags: java, grails, groovy, youtube-api

Greatings!
I've been tasked on a groovy/grails project to display YouTube videos relating to the project that are marked private. I'm guessing they want to keep the videos accessible but only through their site. So I've been given the YouTube dev api guide and asked to make it work.

Got my dev key and I'm still waiting for client login info but, wonder if I'm even barking up the right tree.

I very briefly looked over the guide, but would like to know if there are any samples/guides using this in web app environment.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  If a video is marked as private, how could there be API to make it publicly viewable?  If there is, then I would guess this has little to do with Groovy or Java and is only relevant to the youtube-api.

Comment: ... of course it does not make any sense. Trying to explain that to some people can be, oh so exciting ;-) Knock on wood, me thinks the issue went away at least for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any Groovy specific information. Since Groovy uses the JVM and can call java librarys with out any problem take a look at the [YOutube Java developers guide](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) Everything in it should apply to Groovy/Grails.

Answer (score 0):

... so I had a chance to look over the api in greater detail and I still don't see a way to make private videos publicly viewable without 'unprivating' them. Am I missing something? At this point I'm just trying to document that what I'm getting asked to do can't or at least should not be done.